# Error querying "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" provider from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is not a question, but this post may be useful for community because I could not find the answer on the Internet.

**Tested on**

- Windows 2008 R2 x64 and Windows 2003 x64
- SQL Server 2008 SP3 x64
- Provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 x64

SQL Server is running under domain account that is not admin of local machine.
SQL Server connection authentication is Windows.

The issue is:

when creating and using a linked server or adhoc querying using this provider, you may receive errors like these:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "xxx" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed"
>
> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "xxx" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC dBASE Driver] Your network access was interrupted. To continue, close the database, and then open it again.
>
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "xxx"
>
> Could not find installable ISAM
>
> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "xxx" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC dBASE Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x16f4 Thread 0x2728 DBC 0x1ce64ae8 Xbase'

The reason is that the provider creates a temporary file in SQL Server's domain account's temporary folder, using user connect's credentials. Ordinary users does not have such permissions.

Comment: Sql server is running under a domain account, which is not used to login on that machine. Please clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

**The solution is**
grant "Modify" permission to sql server users on Sql Server's domain account's temporary folder.
This folder ordinarily is

- Windows 2003: "c:\Documents and
  Settings\sql_server_account_name\Local Settings\Temp\"
- Windows 2008: "C:\Users\sql_server_account_name\AppData\Local\Temp\"

Comment: I moved the solution that Boogier had originally posted as part of his question.  Made CW so I don't get undue rep.